# I got a ton of excel files and am trying to extract the second sheet of each of these excel files

Tags: python, pandas

Each excel's second sheet is named in two ways: either Applicant-New or Applicant-Recurring. I used the code below to extract only the Applicant-New data but my df returned both Applicant-New and Applicant-Recurring data.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

for i in files_xlsx:
    df = pd.read_excel(i, sheet_name="Applicant-New")
    new_row = {"Application No.":df.iloc[0,0]}
    consolidated_df = consolidated_df.append(new_row, ignore_index = True)
```

How do I resolve this issue so that I only get Applicant-New data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC? Using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and list comps:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


files = [file for file in Path.cwd().glob("*.xlsx")]

consolidated_df = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame([[{"Application No.": pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="Applicant-New").iloc[0, 0]}]]) for file in files]
).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={0: "applications"})

print(consolidated_df)
```

Output:

```
             applications
0  {'Application No.': 1}
1  {'Application No.': 4}
2  {'Application No.': 7}
```